# SQL Take filter from a value from a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamicquery

I have a table with different columns. Each column contains a filter.

| Course | Filter1 | Filter2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | and startdate > '20200101' | and active = 0 |
| Second | and startdate > '20210101' | and active = -1 |

I want to dynamically create a SQL with those filter

```
DECLARE @filter1 as varchar(1000)
DECLARE @filter2 as varchar(1000)
DECLARE File_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT filter1, filter2 FROM _table_filters

OPEN File_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM File_Cursor INTO @filter1, @filter2;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(8000) = ' 
        select   statusdate  
        from t_table   
        where 1=1
        '''+@filter1+''' 
        '''+@filter2+''' 
    '
    exec(@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM File_Cursor INTO @filter1, @filter2;
END;

CLOSE File_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE File_Cursor;
```

However the query has filter with single quotes and I can't get it right.

```
select   statusdate  
from t_table   
where 1=1
'and startdate > '20200101'' 
'and active=0'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, for instruction you don't need additional quotes

```sql
    declare @sql varchar(8000) = ' 
        select   statusdate  
        from t_table   
        where 1=1 ' + @filter1 + '  ' + @filter2
```

Comment: Of course you are a genious!